# Apple script getting Syntax error - Error: Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”

Tags: macos, applescript, applescript-objc

```
#! /usr/bin/osascript
osascript -e "do shell script 
"chmod 777 /Library/ColorSync/Profiles" with administrator privileges"
```

Error:
Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”.

I am new to apple script. I need to run this with NSAppleScript. AS first step, from the script editor I am getting the above error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `#!/usr/bin/osascript` shebang. You don't need to call `osascript` in your code. Just do:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
do shell script "foo"
```

Comment: Executed this #! /usr/bin/osascript
osascript -e 'do shell script 
"chmod 777 /Library/ColorSync/Profiles" with administrator privileges' Getting same error. Instead of """, message become unknown character

Comment: See my edit. I forgot this was in a script and I didn't notice the shebang

Comment: #! /usr/bin/osascript
osascript -e do shell script "chmod 777 /Library/ColorSync/Profiles" with administrator privileges                                                                                -getting same error

Comment: You _don't need to call_ `osascript` in your script because the shebang already uses the AppleScript command. Read the second script carefully. Actually, I'll just remove the first one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880124/apple-script-working-fine-but-with-objective-c-library-not-getting-expected-out